# How to create end connection in AWS s3 out node in node-red?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, node-red

I have a usecase where I want to upload my local file to s3 bucket and further continue next process. So, I am using `amazon s3 out` node. it uploads file properly but it's not allowing me to perform further operations. Because the node has one was connection.

[image]

How to perform next operation using this node? Any hint would be appreciable.

Comment: Do you need to wait for the upload to finish before continuing?

Comment: yes, I want to hit an API once upload is completed. But, I am unable to get the status of uploading.

Comment: Does the node show any status (text and a circle just under the node) while uploading?

Comment: yes, it shows. the node works properly. it uploads file to s3 bucket. I want to capture once file has been uploaded. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 options

1. Modify the node to have an output. If you do this you should consider raising a pull request against the project so the authors can decide if they want to include your changes.
2. Split the flow into 2 parts. And then use the AWS watch node (included in the same package as the AWS s3 output node you are using) to watch for the event that matches the file being uploaded. You will have to store any data that is included with the file you are uploading in the [context](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/context) so it can be retrieved by the second flow.
3. Is pretty much the same as option 2, but you can use the Status node instead to watch for changes in status of the AWS output node to trigger the later steps.

Out of three options I'd probably follow them in the same order

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. option-2 takes long time(~10 mins). Option-3 always gives undefined

Comment: Read the doc for the status node, it does NOT use `msg.payload`